# MPLABX : How to Read/Write 4 bytes unsigned integer to EEPROM?

Tags: pic, c, i2c, microchip, mplabx

My question looks simple but still I lost my way to get the issue resolved. Discussion might show me the way.

I am using Pic16f877A microcontroller to write EEPROM using I2C ( 1 Byte at a time ). I need to write 4Bytes integer value (lets say 4284967295 ~ 0xFF67697F). I want to write this value to the EEPROM and Read this value from EEPROM whenever needed.
I am unable to find best possible ways to write/read this value.

I tried approaching following way :

```
unsigned int a = 4284967295;
unsigned int result1, result2, result3, result4;
result1 = (( a & 0x000000FF ) ); \\ result1 = 127
result2 = (( a & 0x0000FF00 ) ); \\ result2 = 26880
result3 = (( a & 0x00FF0000 ) ); \\ result3 = 6750208
result4 = (( a & 0xFF000000 ) ); \\ result4 = 4278190080
```

but lost the way.
And reference, link, and your guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!!!!!

Comment: The relevant product's datasheet contains valuable example code: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39582C.pdf (page 35). If something's unclear, ask what specifically. 
EDIT: Ah, I misunderstood the question. Luckily two quick answerers already solved the problem for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that you're not shifting the bits along as you read them into the result and also depending on the compiler an `unsigned int` might not be large enough for a 32-bit value. The following code is from a non-Microchip project but should show you one idea. Using the `stdint.h` header in your projects is generally a good idea because you can easily see the size of the data types and not rely on compiler dependant sizes.

```
#include <stdint.h>

void write_eeprom_int32(uint16_t addr, uint32_t data)
{
    write_eeprom(addr, data & 0xFF);
    write_eeprom(addr + 1, data >> 8 & 0xFF);
    write_eeprom(addr + 2, data >> 16 & 0xFF);
    write_eeprom(addr + 3, data >> 24 & 0xFF);
}

uint32_t read_eeprom_int32(uint16_t addr)
{
    uint32_t result;

    result = read_eeprom(addr + 3);
    result <<= 8;
    result += read_eeprom(addr + 2);
    result <<= 8;
    result += read_eeprom(addr + 1);
    result <<= 8;
    result += read_eeprom(addr);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: For my solution with CodeVisionAVR, it works using [&0xFF] after ALL shifting (data&0xFF, data>>8&0xFF, data>>16&0xFF, and data>>24&0xFF)

Comment: That code came from a project where the value was an 8-bit so it would be truncated, but thanks it was worth updating to make it more generic because that's not guaranteed behavior between compilers and libraries.

Answer (score 3):

One simple solution is to use a `union` to redefine your `unsigned long` to 4 bytes (note that your `unsigned int` is only 2 bytes in XC8):

```
union
{
    uint32_t      uNumber;  // exactly 4 bytes, no larger
    unsigned char uByte[4];
} myUnion;

// write to eeprom ...
myUnion.uNumber = 4284967295;
for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    // write myUnion.uByte[i] to eeprom here
}

// read from eeprom ...
for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    // read myUnion.uByte[i] from eeprom here
}
unsigned long uNumberRead = myUnion.uNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned long int a = 4284967295;

unsigned char result[4];

result[0]=a;

result[1]=a>>8;

result[2]=a>>16;

result[3]=a>>24;

j=0;

for(i=*starting_address* ;  i<= *starting_address + 4*  ; i++)

{

  write_eeprom(i,result[j]);

  j++;

}
```